# Android Studio - Displaying an ArrayList of objects

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android Studio, and I am trying to display an ArrayList of objects on a single activity in Android Studio.

Basically, I just want the object's fields to be displayed in a row, with the next object being displayed right below it.

The object I'm trying to display only has 3 fields. For example, the object person would have values for a firstName, lastName, and an address.

I have seen things similar to this using a ListView, however the examples I've seen have only displayed one field. I'm not really sure how to proceed

Comment: What is problem if object has 3 fields? Are you want it can scroll horizontal or st?

Comment: I am trying to have the 3 fields horizontal and then the list itself is vertical. I'm not sure how I would implement that

Comment: Use [Recyclerview](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/recyclerview?gclid=CjwKCAjwzY2bBhB6EiwAPpUpZloFDS_Qse3gMnmeVxWYOqZENf7eDJwvD5GAZWZED1DOlLlLGR2v7hoCJ5YQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) for proper implementation

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a ArrayList, i recommend you use RecyclerView, the effective successor of ListView or GridView. For more details and example you can follow here: [RecyclerView from Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/recyclerview)

For your case you need to define a RecyclerView in your xml layout. Create a xml layout for display object fields and then create a RecyclerView adapter to inflate your view. Hope this help.